# How to set up Zend Route to use an additional 'parameter' prior to the MVC paramters?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-route

My situation is this:
The application I'm working on uses the sub-domain to detect 'who' the client is.
ie: client1.site.com, client2.site.com
That's all working fine (and I'm not using any special routes).

Now however, I have a need to put my code into a 'test' environment. In this case though, I'm restricted to a single subdomain.
ie: *static.testsite.com*

My thought was to use Zend Routing to a degree so that I can convert the Request as follows:
***static.testsite.com/client1/...***
or 
***static.testsite.com/client2/...***

So the first 'parameter' needs to be the client name followed by the standard MVC parameters (module/controller/action).

I plan to add this Routing logic to the routeStartup hook of a Controller Plugin only available in the test environment.

First, is there an easier way to accomplish this job that I haven't thought of?
Second, if not, does anyone have any experience with this sort of requirement?

I'm at the moment experimenting with the different routes that Zend provide but thus far, I've been unsuccessful (the client name keeps becoming the controller, etc).

Any help is much appreciated.
Thank you.

Edit: I tried doing this in an ugly way by manipulating the request uri of the request object. However, this leaves the rest of the site without the /clientX/ portion in their urls thus causing further issues. And updating all locations with the /clientX/ portions is not really feasible either. So though I can retrieve the client, the rest of the site remains non-functional which makes me think that a Route is the only way.

Edit #2: I got it working with the following code;

```
// within a Controller Plugin at routeStartup

    $oFrontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $oRouter = $oFrontController->getRouter();

    $oNewDefaultRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
            ':testClient/:controller/:action/*',
            array(
                'module' => 'default',
                'controller' => 'index',
                'action' => 'index',
                'testClient' => null,
            )
        );

    $oRouter->addRoute('default', $oNewDefaultRoute);
```

The problem remained however, since it doesn't affect any of the existing urls. So trying to access any of them leads to a place without the testClient thus causing errors. I believe some session based solution following the initial 'client' assigning will need to be adopted.

If however, someone knows of a more elegant way to do it, do let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Why not use client1test.testsite.com? In effect its a separate client but that allows you to have a completely separate test vs production environment

Comment: That would have been ideal as it wouldn't really need any of these changes. Unfortunately, the problem is that these are actual domains/sub-domains and because of that I am unable to create sub-domains for each of these clients on the test environment. As mentioned above "I'm restricted to a single subdomain".

Comment: Is the `/clientX` part _always_ in the URL? Do you have cases where this part is ommitted and the first parameter is module or controller?

Comment: For the test environment, it'll *always* has to be there. So you can assume it's always there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ini-based solution suggestion, untested - just for general idea:

```
routes.withClient.route = ":client/:module/:controller/:action/*"
routes.withClient.defaults.module = "default"
routes.withClient.defaults.controller = "index"
routes.withClient.defaults.action = "index"
```

Value of `client` accessible through `$request->getParam('client')`.

Comment: Thanks bububaba. I didn't test this out as I got it working within the Controller Plugin. However, instead of a new route, I overwrote the existing default route instead. I marked it as the answer since there doesn't seem to be any other way with Routes to do exactly what I want. Thanks for your help in any case.